# how to create a dynamic password thats between 8 and 16 characters

Tags: bash

This is my password generator and it generates 8 characters and shuffles them. But i need to make it dynamic length. How would i go about doing that. So the output would be different length between 8 - 16 characters.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
num=("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "7" "8" "9")
special=("@" "#" "$" "%" "*" "-" "+")
upper=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
lower=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
lower2=${#lower[*]}   #${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}
upper2=${#upper[*]}   #${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}
num2=${#num[*]}     #${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}
special2=${#special[*]} #${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}

echo "${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}" | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d '\n'
echo
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

One rough possibility that I just now put together (so YMMV but it's at least a starting point):

```
head /dev/urandom | tr -cd '[:alnum:]' | tail -c $(( $RANDOM % 8 + 8 ))
```

Characters will be alphanumeric so you may want to play around with the `tr` character set.

Some example strings generated:

```
yoXvUVnHG7IIDe
tQGHN7g1rdtbtRO
jsguP1rmJ
CAcoVMK4Ij
KNHVxE8hO
XDkCgx1bN
pijB0Vgx
060qBI9X
LRxp4Ciiab4VCq
tJGYLpof
TVxMPIcjoCKnyA
JYUd4C83TOxr0N
pZaT0lZvNw3oAA
ojtsMD6Ic8E3
UBxtFUY1uy9eT
```